# How can I use MongoDB's $text and $nearSphere search operators together?

Tags: mongodb, search, geojson

I have some documents with a few string fields and some embedded GeoJSON points, like this:

```
{
   title: "",
   description: "",
   geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [0,0]
   }
}
```

**So as per [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/#special-indexes-restriction), MongoDB's full-text operator and geo search operators can't be used in the same query.**

That kind of makes sense to me because they both try to sort the same results in different ways, so what's a good alternative way to:

- first, filter the documents for user-supplied search term matches
- then, sort the matching documents by distance from user-supplied coordinates

Phrased another way, I would like to use the full-text search algorithm simply to **filter rather than sort**, and the opposite for the geo search operation. This seems sound in principle, and certainly many location-aware apps let you do this this (eg. rightmove, deliveroo, airbnb and so on), so what's the best approach?

I think I'd be able to do something *acceptably* good by using `$or` and regex values across multiple fields, but I doubt the results would be as good or as speedy as using the native search algorithm.

Aggregations don't seem to help with this, though I'm starting to read about map-reduce, which seems like it could offer a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you:

- `$match` using the text index
- use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/#exp._S_let) to calculate the distance manually
- sort by the calculated distance

?